# Eclipse isn't updating custom methods in JSP scriptlets

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, scriptlet

I'm editing a Dynamic Web Project, with a simple class in the project's /src folder, and a .jsp page to access it.

Within Eclipse, .jsp page only recognizes some of the methods in my class as existing -- other classes get "The method ... is undefined" and "The method ... is not visible", even though the code all compiles and works like I would expect it to. But this only happens sometimes.

```
<%
myConnectionDBO = ConnectionDBO.getInstance();
out.println("Is connected? "
        + myConnectionDBO.isConnected()
        + "<br>");
out.println("Attempting resultset grab...<br>");

ResultSet rs = myConnectionDBO.doSelectWhere(1);
%>
```

- `.getInstance()` doesn't have any syntax errors (but it should, because it was added later).
- `.isConnected()` shows an undefined error (false positive).
- `.doSelectWhere()` shows "is not visible" and "cannot convert from void to ResultSet" (ditto).

Before you ask, I have rebuilt/cleaned my project, refreshed it from the Project Explorer, auto-build is enabled, restarted my application server (JBoss), and restarted Eclipse. The problems remain.

Comment: Sounds like your are using scriptlets <% %> to mix Java code with HTML inside your JSP, that will make a mess out of your project, I recommend you to stop right now, and use JSTL and an MVC framework like Spring-MVC, here is a nice tutorial: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Comment: I'll update my post to reflect that. Indeed scriptlets seem awfully dense, and Spring is definitely in my future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you MUST do what the previous post recommends (JSTL + EL = awesomness) i'm wondering wether you missed the <%@ page ...> directive to import classes that would contain the definition of those methods.

Comment: After looking back I've actually included that too (not purposely but via template) -- but I fixed it by using much, much less code in the JSP's themselves.